Renaming vaticle-typedb and vaticle-typeql to typedb and typeql
Can we rename vaticle-typedb and vaticle-typeql to typedb and typeql?
The organization has been renamed from Vaticle to TypeDB, which you can see in TypeDB LinkedIn and TypeDB GitHub org, and the company domain is fully renamed to typedb.com (and typeql.com redirects to it).
So, the brand "Vaticle" no longer exist, and the names "TypeDB" and "TypeQL" are now fully known for the TypeDB database and the TypeQL language, as also published in ACM this year: TypeQL: A Type-Theoretic & Polymorphic Query Language.
At this point, adding "vaticle-" prefix now causes confusions to many users (especially new ones).
N. B.: I am the creator of TypeDB & TypeQL.

Any takers for typedb-typedb and typedb-typeql ? Hey, I can't help it they named themselves after the product.

@Gimby What would be the reason to name the tags by company-product? Is there a rule on StackOverflow that it has to be the case? Nowhere else on the internet do people refer to TypeDB as typedb-typedb and TypeQL as typedb-typeql.

typescript tag is not called microsoft-typescript @Gimby

reactjs tag is not called facebook-reactjs or meta-reactjs. I can go on, but I think the we get the gist?

@haikalpribadi: The goal is to avoid ambiguity. Since it previously was named vaticle-typedb that suggests that the namer may have thought that just typedb was too ambiguous. If it was too ambiguous then it might be too ambiguous now. Note that at the bottom of their webpage (https://typedb.com/) it says © 2024 Vaticle Ltd. Vaticle™, TypeDB™ and TypeQL™ are trademarks of Vaticle Ltd so maybe we could just leave things the way they are.

If the goal is to avoid ambiguity (and I presume confusion too), then calling it vaticle-typedb right now doesn't help for the sake of our users @PresidentJamesK.Polk. That trademark still refers to Vaticle Ltd because the parent company of TypeDB Inc (in the US) is actually Vaticle Ltd. But this should weigh less when we think of our user. The direct company that TypeDB belongs in, is TypeDB Inc, and all the names on the internet referring to the company is called TypeDB. When you search for 'typedb' or 'typeql' on the internet right now it only returns results for our TypeDB and TypeQL.

If you think it could cause ambiguity, can you please help me understand examples of how this ambiguity could happen at this moment or in the future? All internet presence of the term 'typedb' and 'typeql' only refers to us. Vaticle Ltd will soon be renamed to TypeDB Ltd, and it's not even the direct company. We own the trademark for both terms internationally. We own the domains typedb.com and typeql.com. Vaticle is not used anywhere to refer to us anymore. Can you please help me explain how adding vaticle- adds more clarity?

In the spirit of avoiding ambiguity for our (and SO) users: they do not search of TypeDB on the internet by searching for Vaticle. The fact that Vaticle Ltd owns TypeDB Inc carries no relevance to them. Finding vaticle-typedb when they search for typedb, and not knowing what "Vaticle" is will only add confusion to them -- which is what has happened. People have asked "What's the right tag on SO?" and "Why vaticle-?". So in the spirit of avoiding ambiguity/confusions for our/SO users, I think it's best to just refer to TypeDB the way that every platform on the internet refers to TypeDB.

History of the current tag names, for reference.

Indeed, @RyanM, and since that post, we now own both trademarks, both domain names, company name changed to TypeDB, and the Vaticle brand has been dissolved. Given the amount of online presence that uniquely has referred to TypeDB in the last several years, and the fact the ACM publishes our technology with the names TypeDB and TypeQL, I think it is fair to say that that 'typedb' and 'typeql' uniquely refers to our technology now. Irrespective of all that, Vaticle no longer carries relevance to tag names on SO.

@haikalpribadi: "we ..." do you work for that company?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk: yes, and I'm trying to help tidy up our community resource right now to help our users who use SO find us easier. Right now, we too often get asked: what's your tag on SO? How would you suggest we make this clear to them?

This question is similar to: Updating product tags after a name change - Grakn + Graql. The answer explains why using [typedb] and [typeql] is not ideal.

@M--SavetheDataDump so much has changed since that last post. So much context at has changed. As of today, can you help me explain, why is 'typedb' and 'typeql' not ideal? Especially given the fact that the brand "Vaticle" has been dissolved. What would be the reason to keep "vaticle-"?

Because of ambiguity. And I don't think a company rebranding themselves counts as so much change in SO world.

How does adding "vaticle-" reduce that ambiguity when users don't know the name Vaticle? How is it different to adding "randomword-" as a prefix? @M--SavetheDataDump

My last response; if one types [typedb], they (user) still get the relevant tags (and questions). IMO, a general name like that makes housekeeping harder for us (curators). It's OK if you feel otherwise and obviously are free to push for that change, I just don't agree with your proposal. Cheers.

Having read the reasoning in Machavity's old answer, and the discussions here, I have no objection to your proposal. I also don't see a big need for it, and I also appreciate the pros and cons of having short pithy names for tags, and as has been explained there are some cons.

@M--SavetheDataDump Your last response didn't explain further. If the term "vaticle" is as relevant as "random" for users, I don't understand how the argument that it "reduces ambiguity" stands. What happens when we dissolve Vaticle Ltd and only TypeDB Inc continues to run (which will happen at some point), what then? Do we carry the legacy name for ever? It's been several years of us owning the domain space of "typedb" on the internet. Isn't it weird that SO moderators don't agree to allow us the general name? It is general (and unique), and we worked hard to achieve that.

Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk . There's a lot value on our side in terms of community management -- a clean and simple name that users easily identify unambiguously goes a long way. We've dropped the "Vaticle" brand for a few years now. And users no longer recognize that name. All the relevant platforms on the internet refer to us as TypeDB, including ACM. We're just left with tidying up SO.

The Tag Wikis for both tags still use /vaticle/ for 2 separate URL's... (Still some clean-up to do...)

Understood, but your interests do not align 100% with ours. We also value clarity, but the consensus for tag names, like everything else, has evolved on this site based on hard experience. You can certainly look through same tag rename proposals here on meta to get an idea of where our concerns come from. And while trademarks should be a consideration, I don't think the volunteers here give much thought to IP issues during our curation. Someone else may decide to create a kablammo-typedb tag and then we'd have confusion between typedb and kablammo-typedb.

Thanks @chivracq -- that's indeed outdated and we should update them.
@PresidentJamesK.Polk It's totally fair for someone to create kablammo-typedb, but that has nothing to do with typedb. Surely it should be fair for us to have the advantage of being called typedb. After all, we put in the work to own the domain, the github org, the brand, the trademark, the company name, and so on. In any case, why would that be a reason to keep the word vaticle- in front of our name if that term no longer refers to us? What would be the prefix if our company was called TypeDB Inc from the start?

Well..., you are shooting in your own foot, by naming the Company like the Product... Don't you plan to develop new products in the future...? Then your own Customers will (again!) get confused about "TypeDB", not knowing anymore if you talk about one of your products or about the company... // Or rename the Product back to "Grakn", then we can use grakn or typedb-grakn for the tag name on 'SO', problem solved...! // "Grakn" + "Graql" were perfect names/tags (because non-generic like "typedb") for 'Google' and 'SO'... Don't rename your products and company every few years...

@chivracq trust me we've learnt the lesson. :) never again will we create a company name different from the product name. But as it stands right now and the vision we have for TypeDB, we'll have our hands full building TypeDB alone for a long time, without coming up with a new product. So right now, the sole and only technology and brand we will be working on is just TypeDB. That's just plain fact. If you guys can help find a unique term to disambiguate TypeDB (a term we own in almost every domain) against other possible 'typedb', then by all means, please do suggest. But "vaticle" is not it.

@chivracq MongoDB also has the same name for their product and company.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk if it helps:

[graphdb] isa generic term (graph + db) that is used to refer to Ontotext GraphDB. And the tag is not called [ontotext-graphdb].
[objectdb] is a generic term (object + db) that is used to refer to objectdb.com

Would you not agree that we can find a lot of precedent on SO that shows that it's fair to name our tag [typedb]?

You can find precedents for many things here, as I've said we have evolved over time and the consensus on how to do things is part of that evolution. I'm fine with your proposal, but I respect the other opinions here that are more hesitant.

Well, about "never again will we create a company name different from the product name", that sounds to me like confusing PK and FK, a bit surprising for sbd designing Databases... Just like a company will have several employees, it can have/develop several products, you don't give a different name for the company to every single employee for them to use, and you don't recreate a new company each time you develop a new product...

@chivracq: We can assume the company guy knows what's best for his company.

I understand where you're coming from @chivracq -- that's why I started with different names. But turns out, wisdom has it that marketing 2 different brands is much harder than 1. That's why most companies start off with the one name for their tech and company -- MongoDB, Facebook, Google, etc. But this conversation is off topic now.

Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk -- I appreciate your input, and everyone's too. I just try my best to explain the reasoning from our side as much as possible.
If you're happy with the proposal, would you be able to help us implement the change? If not, can you help give me feedback on further steps we should take to make sure we comply with moderation rules? Thank you!

@haikalpribadi Creating the tags is not possible, because they're already a synonyms of their vaticle- variants, so probably a moderator has to undo that first, and in this regard, just switch the synonym around, or even merge the tags.

Thanks, @Lino -- do we know who can help us do that?

Well, about MongoDB, only typing "mongo" both in 'Google' or 'SO' only yields results related to 'MongoDB', try the same with "type" or "typed", => absolutely nothing related to 'TypeDB'..., that's the problem... But "typedb" on 'SO' does correctly yield the only 2 relevant Tags, so your Users asking for the correct Tag(s) on 'SO' sounds a bit void to me. Maybe the Tag Excerpts for both Tags could be made a bit clearer, or you could educate your Users from your own Site to direct them to the correct Tags on 'SO'. // Or typedb-typedb from 'Gimby' is maybe not that bad as I first thought...


The confusion is mainly on the question: "what's vaticle?", "is this you guys?" -- why add this this confusion?
What would we achieve by going with typedb-typedb @chivracq? Will we have disambiguated the typedb database built by the typedb guys? Doesn't it prove the point that we are the first mover to utilize (effectively) the term typedb?
In all fairness, don't we think it's rather unlikely for someone to come up with another tech called TypeDB at this point given how much of that brand we've owned on all tech platforms? Even ACM attributes TypeDB and TypeQL to us now.


also, we're not asking to name the tag type @chivracq -- that wouldn't make sense. We're asking it to be typedb which uniquely refers to us. Even on Google it only takes you to our work.

When searching for "typedb" in various search engines the top results seem to only be about this so I guess it would probably be okay to not have a company name as a prefix for the tag.

Well, the problem is that typedb and typeql are too short and too generic for 'SO', Askers on 'SO' are very-very-very lazy with typing only 3-4-5 Chars and selecting the first Tag that looks/sounds a bit similar to the "correct" Tag they shoud select. Those 2 are not really an option for Tag-names (even if they already exist as Synonyms), => you come up with a viable proposition... If you don't like typedb-typedb, give us some ideas we can vote on... (And next time you develop a product, don't call it "TypeXXX" or "EdgeXXX" or "Team(s)XXX"...!)

Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat -- especially if the company has been renamed.

@chivracq why is it possible for graphdb and objectdb? They are are short and general as typedb. In fact, [edgedb] does exist: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/edgedb/info
If graphdb, objectdb, and as recent as edgedb can all get their names written simply, why can't typedb?

Because "graphd" and "objectd" already do the job (the disambiguation), while "typed" doesn't...

@chivracq Is that an actual limitation on the system -- that it has to at least be more than 1 letter disambiguation? And what about typeq -- surely that won't yield anything?

OK, I gave you my 2cts-Feedback, if you had so much time and energy in finding contra-examples every time sbd tries to give you some Feedback, you could better have spent that time and energy thinking of a searchable and unique and recognizable name for your product(s) and company name... (I'm a bit out now..., good luck further, I'll check the Thread a bit later or tomorrow...)

@chivracq typedb IS that unique term that people use to find our product! For a few years now! Have you tested entering that term on Google yet?

is typedb a term that describes something other than the product? is this the only company that provides this particular.... thing? seems odd to me as far as how to... describe it. What is it. Is there an existing tag that already covers what this product is that isn't either of these tags? They seem fairly low in usage as it is.

Thanks @KevinB — no typedb does not describe anything other than this product. Yes, we are the only company building a TypeDB. It’s a type-theoretic database. The existing tag is vaticle-typedb, which we are trying to get renamed. It is fairly low usage cause we are new.

Right, but like, that's the point. it's a "type-theoretic database". If another company came along and created a similar product that is a "type-theoretic database", wouldn't it make more sense to have a tag that would describe both? Put another way, Why does business marketing (the company name) need to be in the tag at all? Of course, as a business you want people searching for your product, but this is an open community,

@KevinB if another type-theoretic database is invented, they will have a different name, that won’t be close. Cause we own the name, trademark, domain, company inc, and all the branding on the internet. That’s not a reasonable expectation to happen. In the same way that graphdb, objectdb, edgedb, typescript, and so on, are named and tagged here in SO. This is not a new thing that we’re inventing, guys. Developers name tools by putting Trait + ToolAbbrevation, all the time. And other developers will come up with new names. There’s no magic here. TypeDB is not a “category” of technology.

If someone comes up with another strongly-typed javascript, no one will expect them to share the name or tag with typescript @KevinB

Mods, I think this exchange has gone beyond reasonableness of discourse. We’ve addressed all concerns with objective proof and reference and it feels like the reasoning to not do this is getting quite arbitrary now.  Do we have an objective reason to not proceed with this?

Doesn't another already exist, that seems to be mentioned in an overwhelming majority of questions currently tagged by one or both of these tags?

No, there is only one TypeDB on the internet and SO and that is in reference to us. @KevinB

How do questions tagged this exist from prior to typedb existing?

@KevinB cause it started from a prior project called grakn that was renamed to typedb

Mods, do we have clarity to move forward on this topic? I believe we've addressed all the concerns raised and we have demonstrated with lots of references on the internet that you can verify, that (a) we own the name TypeDB wholly and rightfully in this space, and (b) "Vaticle" is no longer a name that identifies us. Given that there is an objective reason to not remove 'vaticle-' from the tag, can we proceed with removing it now?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk we've removed the Vaticle Ltd trademark ownership note from our footer as it's misleading now. So there is no more reference of Vaticle.

@haikalpribadi It hasn't been that long since you posted this question and there's no need to rush the moderators into making a decision. Given this request had some discussion where people disagreed with it, it's natural for the mods to give the community more time to discuss and come to a consensus before taking action.

@AbdulAzizBarkat okay sounds good! Thanks, Abdul!

Hi Mods, any thoughts or updates on the topic above? It's been a few weeks since the post was made.

@haikalpribadi if you want to catch the attention of anyone you'd be better off editing this question or if you specifically want mods to have a look you can raise a flag for them. Comments don't really notify anyone unless you @ mention them, I only noticed your comment because I noticed it in a chat room some of the community members use for tracking new comments on Meta (Some moderators do monitor this chat but depending on that to catch their attention isn't reliable).
